# How to search Data in jTable using MS Acess using ComboBox with jTextField Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox, netbeans-6.9

In my program I can search data in jTable with this code using jTextfield "txtsearch" in my program.

Please take a look at my actual program. Here is a picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZguC.png]

This is my code in jTextField "txtsearch". In this code
I can search the jTable via `Name` only. I want to search by using the jComboBox.

```
String a=txtsearch.getText();
conn=MyConnection.ConnectDB();
String sql="Select* from StdRecord WHERE Name LIKE'"+a+"%'";
try{
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rst=pst.executeQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rst));
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Also, based on the image that I have uploaded, my question is: How can I search student by `Name`, `MiddleName` and `Surname` using the combo box?
For Example, I select `MiddleName` in the combo box, then when I type in the jTextField "txtsearch" I can only search in `MiddleName` part of the table.

Comment: **(1)** You can have your code inspect the selected jComboBox value and substitute `MiddleName` or `Surname` for `Name` in the SQL command text. **(2)** You should be using a *parameterized query* (i.e., `... LIKE ?` along with `pst.setString(...)`) to protect yourself against SQL injection issues, like when `Surname` is `O'Connor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my code in jTextField "txtsearch". In this code I can search the jTable via Name only. I want to search by using the jComboBox.

Your current SQL uses a variable for the data you want to search for so why can't you use a variable for the column you want to search?

```
String a=txtsearch.getText();
String column = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
String sql="Select* from StdRecord WHERE " + column + "LIKE'"+a+"%'";
```

Also, to make the SQL a little easier to code and maintain you should use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "Select* from StdRecord WHERE " + column + "LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, a + "%" );
stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Hello sir @camickr. What do you mean by that. For the column i want to search? I'm just a beginner sir. Please help me with my project :(

Comment: You have 3 columns in your database "Name", "MiddleName", "Surname". You can't hard code "Name" in the SQL because you don't know which column the user wants to search on.

Comment: I finally did it sir. I understand now. That my txtsearch field is based on the 3 columns to search. Thank you sir. I can pass my project tomorrow! Thanks for the big help sir camickr.  God bless!! 

P.S.
Sorry for the grammar.